# Git check file contents across branches

Tags: bash, git

I'm currently using the following two bash functions to chunk through our git repo to determine what the latest version number is on each branch.  Since we have several git hooks, including post-checkout, the `gitTrackAll` function can take quite a while to run.  Is there any way to do what I'm doing without checking out every branch, pulling it in, then running a git show?

To clarify, I'm currently checking out each branch and getting the contents of the VERSION file.  This essentially tells me what the last version that was merged into that branch is.  We occasionally have some branches that stagnate while the developer is working on them. This list provides us a quick way to see what's way behind.

`gitTrackAll && gitBranchVersions`

```
function gitTrackAll(){
        remote='origin';
        for brname in `git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD| awk '{gsub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do
            git checkout "$brname"
            git branch --set-upstream-to $remote/$brname $brname;
            git pull
        done
        git checkout master
}

function gitBranchVersions(){
        line='--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
        line="$line$line"
        for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/); do
                VER=$(git show "$branch":VERSION);
                printf "%s %s $VER\n" $branch "${line:${#branch}}"
        done
}
```

The resulting output looks a little like the following (branch names changed)

```
refs/heads/1954-branch-a ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.9.27
refs/heads/1955-branch-b ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.9.43
refs/heads/1965-branch-c ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.9.32
refs/heads/1968-branch-d ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.9.101
refs/heads/1969-branch-e ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.9.114
refs/heads/master ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.9.115
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can read files straight from remote. Using pieces from both functions, I've come up with the following, which works perfectly for the application I need.

```
function gitBranchVersions(){
    line='--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    line="$line$line"
    remote='origin' ;

    git fetch --all --prune
    for brname in `git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v HEAD| awk '{gsub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do
        VER=$(git show "$remote/$brname":VERSION);
        printf "%s %s $VER\n" $brname "${line:${#brname}}"
    done
}
```

Comment: `git fetch --all` fetches all *remotes*, not all branches.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite `gitTrackAll` the following way without any checkout at all:

```
function gitTrackAll(){
        remote='origin';
        for brname in `git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD| awk '{gsub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do
            git branch --set-upstream-to $remote/$brname $brname;
            # git fetch cannot update the current branch - use git pull
            git fetch $remote $brname:$brname || git pull $remote $brname
        done
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the ``git pull`` pull in changes from the remote branch to whatever branch I'm currently on though?

Comment: Yeah, it's changing the upstream tracking for your current branch, then fetching and pulling the changes on to your current branch. I'm sure that will lead to all sorts of fun. :)

Comment: @GameCharmer Very much depends on the settings. I prefer to be explicit in shell scripts and shorten commands in the command line.